# What is best approach to create index on multiple columns for multiple like query (e.g. like field1% and field2% ) in mysql

Tags: mysql, database, database-performance

I understand that indexes can't be used if my query parameter is like %val1% unless it is a full text search index. So I am trying to design a good index for my below query.

What could a good index for the below query look like. Is writing this kind of query not a good practice?

```
select * from table1
where
  field1 like 'search_value1%' 
  and (field2 like 'search_value2%' or field2 is null) 
  and (field3 like 'search_value3%' or field3 is null) 
  and (field4 like 'search_value4%' or field4 is null) 
  and field5 like 'search_value5%' 
  and (field6 like 'search_value6%' or field6 is null) 
  and field7 like 'search_value7%'
```

Comment: What is the selectivity for each separate condition `fieldX LIKE 'search_valueX%'`?

Comment: search_valueX will be fairly unique in most cases but could be similar too..

e.g. field1=last_name, field2=phone_number

Comment: If some column is close to unique than it is enough to have the index by this column... server will check 5-10 rows for all another conditions using table scan fast enough.

Comment: I think relational databases are not born for such a usage. Even I am not sure if that type of multiple search is really necessary for any application. Perhaps you have a general design problem but as we do not know what you try to achieve we cannot now. If you really need full text search over many columns an other database might be the better solution

Comment: This is a user table that I am trying implement comprehensive search for by multiple columns.

Answer (score 0):

Does the user enter 7 different values?  More likely, the user will enter one value and leave the other 6 empty?  In this case, don't try to do it in a single canned query.  Instead, dynamically build the query based on which field (or fields) are filled in in the form.

Then you might construct, say

```
select * from table1
where
      (field2 like 'search_value2%' or field2 is null) 
  and  field5 like 'search_value5%'
```

And have these 7 indexes:

```
 INDEX(field1),
 INDEX(field2),
 ...
 INDEX(field7)
```

There is little advantage in using composite indexes in this query.

If the queries are mostly "words", consider combining all the columns into one and using a `FULLTEXT` index.  (There are many caviats.  Since I don't know what fieldN is, I can't be more specific.)